# How can I scan my entire website and audit it for installed JavaScript tags?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a website on a dev server that I want to scan for Google Tag Manager tags and Google Analytics tags to make sure everything's in place properly.

Currently I have the Google Tag Assistant and the Ghostery Chrome extensions installed to help, but I don't want to go page by page looking for tags.

Does anyone have a best practice method for doing tag auditing on a website?

Comment: Are you primarily looking to find pages that are missing tags, or are you hoping to catch duplicate or unexpected tags?

Comment: Well, like I said, I'm basically looking to do an audit. I'd be interested in seeing duplicates, missing tags, unexpected tags, but just all tags in general so I can have an idea of what tags are where.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone ever comes across this same question, I found a strategy that helped me out. I used Screaming Frog and set up custom filters to contain the tags that were in my Analytics and Tag Manager accounts. Then I just crawled my website and it returned all the pages that contained the tags that I set up.